# Regex capture only the last child, not all

Tags: regex

I would like to play a regexp on each lines:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
# 127.0.0.1 fake
1.2.3.4 foo bar baz
```

The goal is to ignore when it starts with a `#`, otherwise I want to capture the ip and each strings after it.

Here is my attempt:

```
{^\s?(?<ip>[^#\s]+)(?:\s+(?<domain>[^\s]+))*$}
```

My problem is that when I play this on `1.2.3.4 foo bar baz` it only capture `baz`, not `foo` and `bar`. I would like every domains.

PS: I'm using PHP. You can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/S8Fzlu/1

Comment: If you're trying to get `foo`, `bar`, `baz` in separate capture groups then no it is not possible because you have only 2 capture groups

Comment: Try this regex: https://regex101.com/r/S8Fzlu/4 (you need to use `preg_match_all`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP regex engine or `PCRE` doesn't allow dynamic capture group creation when using a group with a quantifier. It returns only the last captured string. That's the reason you're seeing `baz` being captured in 2nd capture group.

However you may leverage `\G` (kind of word boundary) and capture all strings using `preg_match_all` using this regex:

```
(?:^\h*(?<ip>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)|(?!^)\G)\h+(?<domain>\S+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S8Fzlu/4)

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match

**Code:**

```
$str = '1.2.3.4 foo bar baz';
$re = '/(?:^\h*(?<ip>(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)|(?!^)\G)\h+(?<domain>\S+)/';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $m);

print_r($m['ip']);
print_r($m['domain']);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.2.3.4
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
)
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => baz
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how php RegEx Works, but this RegEx Works in JavaScript and C#, give it a try:

```
^\s?(?<ip>[^#\s]+)(?:\s+(?<domain>[^.]+)*)$
```

Note I have moved the '*' outside the parantese.